# Null pointer exception SQLite Alarm database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey devs I am new to android development I am facing a problem I m creating a alarm app which timings I myself insert into the database and I want the alarm to trigger at that time.

Here is my code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final String PREF_NAME = "Preferences";
    Context context;
    static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    static AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Switch switch1;
    Intent intentAlarm;

    DatabaseHandler dhb = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmReciver.class);

        // setting Time!
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting...");
        dhb.createAlarm(new AlarmModel(1, 1, 21, 5));

        context = MainActivity.this;

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.tgButton);

        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {

                if (seherBtn.isChecked()) {

                    List<AlarmModel> alarms = dhb.getAlarms();

                    for (AlarmModel al : alarms) {
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                                al.getId(), intentAlarm,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
                        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
                        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, al.getDay());
                        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, al.getTimeHour());
                        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, al.getTimeMinute());
                        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    }


                } else {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


                }
            }

        });

    }
```

And my DatabaseHelper class 
Please help me if I m going wrong somewhere and please suggest me the possible solution 
Thanks...

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarmClock.db";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "alarm";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_HOUR = "hour";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_MINUTE = "minute";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_DAYS = "days";
    public static final String ID = "id";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ALARM = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_NAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_HOUR
            + " INTEGER," + COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_MINUTE + " INTEGER,"
            + COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_DAYS + " INTEGER," + " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ALARM = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ALARM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ALARM);
    }

    private AlarmModel populateModel(Cursor c) {
        AlarmModel model = new AlarmModel();
        model.id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ID));
        model.timeHour = c
                .getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_HOUR));
        model.timeMinute = c.getInt(c
                .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_MINUTE));
        model.day = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_DAYS));

        return model;
    }

    private ContentValues populateContent(AlarmModel model) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_HOUR, model.timeHour);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_TIME_MINUTE, model.timeMinute);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_ALARM_DAYS, model.day);
        return values;
    }

    public long createAlarm(AlarmModel model) {
        ContentValues values = populateContent(model);
        return getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public AlarmModel getAlarm(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ID + " = "
                + id;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);

        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            return populateModel(c);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public long updateAlarm(AlarmModel model) {
        ContentValues values = populateContent(model);
        return getWritableDatabase().update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(model.id) });
    }

    public int deleteAlarm(long id) {
        return getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }

    public List<AlarmModel> getAlarms() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);

        List<AlarmModel> alarmList = new ArrayList<AlarmModel>();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            alarmList.add(populateModel(c));
        }

        if (!alarmList.isEmpty()) {
            return alarmList;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please Post your LogCat messages

Comment: if you have added some new table . then you must change the version. try by changing version of database

Comment: @Elenasys Ok I will post the logCat messages  nope I didnt added any tables I think the problem is that list view

Comment: Jack, is better to have more detailed info posting the LogCat messages, than supossing the listview is your problem.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out

Comment: @JackCykor, Post the solution here as an answer and accept the answer. It'll helpful to someone who reaches here.